# iOS Bluetooth LE. Clear cached services

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I connect an iOS device (central) to a non iOS device (peripheral). Peripheral can run 2 different programs, so that it can advertises 2 different kind of services and characteristics.

I think iOS central caches some data such as peripheral name and services. Is it possible to clear that cached data?

I had a similar issue with Android that I solved with this:
[How to programmatically force bluetooth low energy service discovery on Android without using cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596951/how-to-programmatically-force-bluetooth-low-energy-service-discovery-on-android/22709467#22709467)

Comment: I have solved the services issue using Service Change Characteristic at peripheral. [Service Changed Characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gatt.service_changed.xml)

Comment: Here's a bit more info on Service Changed characteristic indication: https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/t/256888

Comment: Can you get in more detail please, maybe write an answer? I'm struggling with the same problem. Do I need to create a characteristic with 0x2A05 UUID in my service (this didn't work for me), or to send 0x2A05 as a Bluetooth opcode from the peripheral to iOS, or run some code on iOS, or what?

Comment: is any one found the solution to clear / refresh Caches about Bluetooth BLE Device?