# Android BLE onCharacteristicChanged stop firing after restarting the app

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I stop getting `onCharacteristicChanged` after exiting the app and restarting it.

Here are the steps I did pairing to a ble device.

1. I have a service that contains the ble logic and persist the `bluetoothGatth` obj, I perform a `blueToothGatt.connect` here on app launch.
2. Once I get `onConnectionStateChange` with `STATE_CONNECTED`, I call `blueToothGatt.discover`
3. On the `onServicesDiscovered` callback, I will fetch and persist the services and characteristics that I care about. Then I will call `blueToothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification` and write to descriptor to enable notification.
4. Now I perform a write and then I will get callback for `onCharacteristicChange` just fine.
5. After this, say I exit the app (device is still paired). The `onDestroy` of the last activity, my ble device service gets unbind...in which I will perform close on `unbind` callback and call `selfstop` to stop the service. Now if I relaunch the app. I will do the same steps 1-4, however this time around `onCharacteristicChange` does not get call, also I tried disconnect before close...but that didn't help

(One thing that I do notice is that if the device is left unpaired/disconnected upon relaunch then the issue occurs, however if I power of the BLE device off and turn it back on before restarting the app, then I get the callback `onCharacteristicChanged` just fine. This seems like the device is holding onto some setting that prevents `onCharacteristics` to get call.)

Any insights to this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. Basically the bluettooth caching the last handle, so discover services is never triggered.  You will need to clear the device cache after connect.

[How to programmatically force bluetooth low energy service discovery on Android without using cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596951/how-to-programmatically-force-bluetooth-low-energy-service-discovery-on-android)