# Wrong GATT profile shows up on BLE tool Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluegiga

So, this will be a pretty basic question. I'm attempting to learn how to program the BGM111 (Blue Gecko) by Blue Giga for the purpose of wireless heart monitoring. This task will be much easier the help of apps like BLE tool. Unfortunately, no matter what app I use, the GATT displayed on the app will somehow "freeze" on a certain program's GATT and although the name of the signal will change on the app, the GATT will not. For example, I am trying out the "Health Thermometer" example from SiliconLab's website. It then has a service called "Health Thermometer". When I try to upload the heart rate example, I look at the BLE tool app and it still has "Health thermometer" listed as a service. I have checked the project file and the GATT file is indeed correct in the heart rate proj file. So what gives? No amount of turning my phone on and off, closing the app, etc. has helped.

Thanks.

Comment: Android caches the GATT information associated with the device, which creates problems if you create a new GATT profile for an existing device. This thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596951/how-to-programmatically-force-bluetooth-low-energy-service-discovery-on-android

Comment: You'll need to show some code here in order for us to be able to help you with anything more than 'iOS and Android cache stuff'

Answer (score 0):

Disable/enable the Android bluetooth adapter to clear your cache in the phone.