# Android Phone cannot connect to Raspberry Pi after changing from Bluetooth to BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have tried this on multiple Android devices. 
We are trying to upgrade our system to work with BLE instead of BT in order to support iOS.

Here is the scenario:

1. Run bleno on Raspberry Pi
2. Connect with Android Phone to BLE -> success
3. Reboot (hard) Raspberry PI and enable bluetooth service
4. Connect and Pair with Android Phone to BT
5. Unpair device in Android Phone
6. Reboot (hard) Raspberry PI, disable bluetooth service and run bleno
7. Connect with Android Phone to BLE -> connection fails (BluetoothGatt status=19)

We tried resetting bluetooth cache (App Manager Storage), and also programmatically ([How to Programmatically Clear Bluetooth Cache using GattServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751811/how-to-programmatically-clear-bluetooth-cache-using-gattserver))
Reboot of Phone also didn't work, HOWEVER, after factory reset of the phone WE WERE ABLE to connect again.

Here is the output of `sudo btmon` on the Raspberry PI during BLE connection before and after:

Before (success):

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                                                     [hci0] 7.416417
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Slave (0x01)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: 6D:B3:5A:EA:CB:50 (Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x01
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13                                                      {0x0002} [hci0] 7.416643
        LE Address: 6D:B3:5A:EA:CB:50 (Resolvable)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 0
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                              [hci0] 7.434359
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                     [hci0] 7.434958
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                        [hci0] 7.435064
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 7.437506
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                    [hci0] 7.437630
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 7.438086
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                        [hci0] 7.438189
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 7.438938
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 7.610374
      ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0001-0xffff
        Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                                                                     [hci0] 8.007841
      LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
        Connection latency: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                     [hci0] 8.022370
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x1d 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 16                                                                   [hci0] 8.022557
      LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Request (0x12) ident 1 len 8
        Min interval: 40
        Max interval: 56
        Slave latency: 0
        Timeout multiplier: 500
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 10                                                                   [hci0] 8.037404
      LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Response (0x13) ident 1 len 2
        Result: Connection Parameters accepted (0x0000)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 18                                                                   [hci0] 8.056423
      ATT: Read By Group Type Response (0x11) len 13
        Attribute data length: 6
        Attribute group list: 2 entries
        Handle range: 0x0001-0x0005
        UUID: Generic Access Profile (0x1800)
        Handle range: 0x0006-0x0009
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (0x1801)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.067455
      ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000a-0xffff
        Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.068874
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 26                                                                   [hci0] 8.093368
      ATT: Read By Group Type Response (0x11) len 21
        Attribute data length: 20
        Attribute group list: 1 entry
        Handle range: 0x000a-0x0014
        UUID: Vendor specific (ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffffff0)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.104908
      ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0015-0xffff
        Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.126027
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Group Type Request (0x10)
        Handle: 0x0015
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.142444
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0001-0x0005
        Attribute type: Include (0x2802)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.143707
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.147126
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0001
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.157415
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0001-0x0005
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 20                                                                   [hci0] 8.160994
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 15
        Attribute data length: 7
        Attribute data list: 2 entries
        Handle: 0x0002
        Value: 020300002a
        Handle: 0x0004
        Value: 020500012a
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.172405
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0005-0x0005
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.172580
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.175935
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0005
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.187369
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0006-0x0009
        Attribute type: Include (0x2802)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.190371
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0006
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.202431
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0006-0x0009
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.203385
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 13                                                                   [hci0] 8.206600
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 8
        Attribute data length: 7
        Attribute data list: 1 entry
        Handle: 0x0007
        Value: 200800052a
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.217417
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0008-0x0009
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.220542
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0008
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.232412
      ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4
        Handle range: 0x0009-0x0009
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.233326
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 10                                                                   [hci0] 8.236097
      ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 5
        Format: UUID-16 (0x01)
        Handle: 0x0009
        UUID: Client Characteristic Configuration (0x2902)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.254911
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000a-0x0014
        Attribute type: Include (0x2802)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.257998
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x000a
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.269937
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000a-0x0014
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.270951
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                                                   [hci0] 8.274584
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 22
        Attribute data length: 21
        Attribute data list: 1 entry
        Handle: 0x000b
        Value: 0a0c0003003333333333333333333333333313
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.284914
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000c-0x0014
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                                                   [hci0] 8.288595
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 22
        Attribute data length: 21
        Attribute data list: 1 entry
        Handle: 0x000e
        Value: 080f0005003333333333333333333333333313
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.307421
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x000f-0x0014
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.308334
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                                                   [hci0] 8.311648
      ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 22
        Attribute data length: 21
        Attribute data list: 1 entry
        Handle: 0x0011
        Value: 10120007003333333333333333333333333313
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 8.322401
      ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0012-0x0014
        Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.325415
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read By Type Request (0x08)
        Handle: 0x0012
        Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.337361
      ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4
        Handle range: 0x000d-0x000d
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.338277
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 10                                                                   [hci0] 8.341007
      ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 5
        Format: UUID-16 (0x01)
        Handle: 0x000d
        UUID: Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.352388
      ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4
        Handle range: 0x0010-0x0010
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 10                                                                   [hci0] 8.355296
      ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 5
        Format: UUID-16 (0x01)
        Handle: 0x0010
        UUID: Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.367413
      ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4
        Handle range: 0x0013-0x0014
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.368251
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 14                                                                   [hci0] 8.371096
      ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 9
        Format: UUID-16 (0x01)
        Handle: 0x0013
        UUID: Client Characteristic Configuration (0x2902)
        Handle: 0x0014
        UUID: Characteristic User Description (0x2901)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                                                    [hci0] 8.382770
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 255
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                    [hci0] 8.385864
      ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
        Server RX MTU: 255
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.397320
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                                                                     [hci0] 8.465343
      LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Connection interval: 60.00 msec (0x0030)
        Connection latency: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.644851
      ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 4
        Handle: 0x0013
          Data: 0100
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                                                    [hci0] 8.648926
      ATT: Write Response (0x13) len 0
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.764880
      ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 4
        Handle: 0x0013
          Data: 0000
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                                                    [hci0] 8.768936
      ATT: Write Response (0x13) len 0
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                    [hci0] 8.884933
      ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 4
        Handle: 0x0013
          Data: 0100
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 8.886011
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                                                    [hci0] 8.890188
      ATT: Write Response (0x13) len 0
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 9.004875
      ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 6
        Handle: 0x000c
          Data: 317c6964
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                                                    [hci0] 9.033321
      ATT: Write Response (0x13) len 0
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 24                                                                   [hci0] 9.125075
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 9.126033
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x01 dlen 24                                                                   [hci0] 9.126060
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x01 dlen 23                                                                   [hci0] 9.127135
      ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 66
        Handle: 0x000f
          Data: 307c307c7b22446576696365416363657373546f6b656e223a2232363465663937302d346362362d313165612d383230612d623832376562316564313439227d
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                                                    [hci0] 9.165770
      ATT: Write Response (0x13) len 0
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 9.432895
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 1
...
```

After (fail):

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                                                     [hci0] 5.509223
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Slave (0x01)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: 48:3F:15:CC:76:5F (Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x01
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13                                                      {0x0002} [hci0] 5.509416
        LE Address: 7C:03:5E:9F:D1:A7 (OUI 7C-03-5E)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 0
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                              [hci0] 5.514306
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                     [hci0] 5.515424
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                        [hci0] 5.515546
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.517443
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                    [hci0] 5.517576
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.518191
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                        [hci0] 5.518314
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.519025
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                        [hci0] 5.545371
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.548676
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) plen 7                                               [hci0] 5.548813
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: 48:3F:15:CC:76:5F (Resolvable)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.550213
      LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                    [hci0] 5.550348
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.551350
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                        [hci0] 5.551468
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                   [hci0] 5.552194
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                                                   [hci0] 5.751468
      ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6
        Handle range: 0x0001-0xffff
        Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                                                                     [hci0] 6.145226
      LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
        Connection latency: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 5000 msec (0x01f4)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                     [hci0] 6.159776
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x1d 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 16                                                                   [hci0] 6.159947
      LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Request (0x12) ident 1 len 8
        Min interval: 40
        Max interval: 56
        Slave latency: 0
        Timeout multiplier: 500
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 10                                                                   [hci0] 6.174753
      LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Response (0x13) ident 1 len 2
        Result: Connection Parameters accepted (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                        [hci0] 6.414272
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 1
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                               [hci0] 10.174344
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                    [hci0] 10.175510
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                               [hci0] 15.169553
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: LMP Response Timeout / LL Response Timeout (0x22)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                   {0x0002} [hci0] 15.169664
        LE Address: 7C:03:5E:9F:D1:A7 (OUI 7C-03-5E)
        Reason: Unspecified (0x00)
```

debian version: 9.3

Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59+ #1047 Sun Oct 29 11:47:10 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux

NOTE: if we change the bluetooth mac address of the Raspberry PI using: https://scribles.net/changing-a-bluetooth-device-address-on-raspberry-pi/, before running bleno, the Android is able to connect to BLE again.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth service (BlueZ) running on Raspberry Pi is the official Bluetooth stack for Linux that has been Bluetooth certified, which should be used unless you have good reasons not to use it. Bleno however is more of a hack, completely separate Bluetooth stack that should only be used for testing purposes and similar, since it has not been certified (and probably has a long way to get there). Pairing/bonding in bleno doesn't really work correctly either. It seems bleno doesn't respond to the received "Read By Group Type Request" and I don't know why, then it sends a Disconnect command.